# Database Connection: Web.config Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

What's wrong with my connection string?
I copied my files from one computer to another. Then I altered my connection string because I moved my files from another computer, it is not connecting to database. When I tried connecting to SQL Management Studio, it successfully connected to my server and when I try running my codes, it didn't.

Here's my Connection String: (Web.config) - My server is Windows Authentication

```
<add name="ConnectionStringMe" connectionString="Data Source=ZOZOW-PC\MSSQLEXPRESS;Database=sample_db;Persist Security Info = True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It gives me error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Is there any conflict if my database is from **SQL Server Authentication** then I moved it to **Windows Authentication**?

Thank you.

Comment: If you went with windows authentication instead of sql authentication then you will need the line 'Integrated Security=True' and you will have to make sure that your sql database has the user added to it with the correct permissions. Also... can you ping 'ZOZOW-PC'... the error says "server not found"...

Comment: For future reference - when I have questions about Connection Strings I always like looking at : http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @beeker i dont know how to ping. Teach me. Thank you

Comment: Go to "Start" > "Command Prompt", this will give you a dos screen and then type "ping ZOZOW-PC"
If you get "Ping request could not find host ZOZOW-PC... then the problem is with your network setup, not the code.  I ask because you mention moving the code to a different computer.

Comment: It displayed my pings with time<1ms on its end. And i believe that it found my computer's host. When I tried connecting my database to my datagridviews datasource, it cant retrieve the database's schema. I already fixed my connection string, it works but gave the same error on different line code. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need this Integrated Security = true into your connection string and it should work. If you don't have this in your connection string you need to specify password and username.

```
<add name="ConnectionStringMe" connectionString="Data Source=ZOZOW-PC\MSSQLEXPRESS;Database=sample_db;Persist Security Info = True;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But gave the same error at different line in my code.

Comment: Also when I tried connecting it to my daagridview's datasource, it can't retrieve schema. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure you are connection only to one database ? Because if the first time has connected there is no reason the second one to not pass.  You may also try to specify the data source as '.' this connects to the local database the same way as when you specify the whole name ZOZOW-PC\MSSQLEXPRESS. Here is how my database connection string is looking <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=UniversitySoftwareSystem;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: It works perfectly now. But Im pretty sure that my host name was ZOZOW-PC and MSSQLEXPRESS. I checked it at Configuration Manager. Anyway, thank you.